# Amazon S3: Set ExpiresByType Headers

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mod-expires

Is it possible to add a blanket S3 bucket policy for expires headers that use the `ExpiresByType`-style directive instead of setting expires headers individually for each file?

My client does most of the uploading of files to S3, and they shouldn't have to learn how (or take the time) to set expires headers for every file. If, however, I could tell S3 to set expires headers automatically based off of what kind of file it is, then everything would be groovy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Headers need to be set on a per-file basis either manually or with a script.